# Typed pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, typescript-typings, angular-pipe

A lot of custom pipes I come across these days are `any` typed, but since I, and my team, would like to make use of the IntelliSense-goodness, I have been playing around with typing some pipes, with no luck.

I spied on the built-in Angular pipe called `slice` which has a definition looking like this: `transform<T>(value: ReadonlyArray<T>, start: number, end?: number): Array<T>;`.

Based on that, I made a simple example for combining two arrays:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'concat'
})
export class ConcatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public transform<T>(
        arr1: ReadonlyArray<T>,
        arr2: ReadonlyArray<T>,
    ): Array<T> {
        return [...arr1, ...arr2];
    }
}
```

**Problem**

My IDE (VS Code) reports the following error when I attempt to use the pipe, and access a property, in my HTML template: `Identifier 'fileStatus' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a member`. "fileStatus" being the property I'm trying to access on the array members in this particular case.

**Question**

Is this not the correct way to type a pipe? Is this not possible (as it seems to be with the built-in `slice`-pipe)?

**Update**

As "Antoniossss" pointed out in his answer, the actual implementation only declares the typed variants and still uses `any` in the actual implementation. I have updated my code as shown below, but IntelliSense is still not provided, and the error still present.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'concat'
})
export class ConcatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public transform<T>(arr1: ReadonlyArray<T>, arr2: ReadonlyArray<T>): Array<T>;
    public transform(
        arr1: any[],
        arr2: any[],
    ): any[] {
        return [...arr1, ...arr2];
    }
}
```

Comment: This does compile in stackblitz, even with the `strict` compiler flag enabled. Stackblitz doesn't have intellisense in html though so there's also that.

Comment: Yeah you're right .

Answer (score 3):

If you check the actual code of `SlicePipe` you will see, that typed variants are only declared for hinting, but not implemented

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/common/src/pipes/slice_pipe.ts

```
 transform<T>(value: ReadonlyArray<T>, start: number, end?: number): Array<T>;
  transform(value: string, start: number, end?: number): string;
  transform(value: null, start: number, end?: number): null;
  transform(value: undefined, start: number, end?: number): undefined;
  transform(value: any, start: number, end?: number): any {
    if (value == null) return value;

    if (!this.supports(value)) {
      throw invalidPipeArgumentError(SlicePipe, value);
    }

    return value.slice(start, end);
  }

  private supports(obj: any): boolean {
    return typeof obj === 'string' || Array.isArray(obj);
  }
```

and all the magic is happening in untyped variant taken from `PipeTransform` interface- `transform(value: any, start: number, end?: number)`.

You will have to do the same

Comment: Thanks for linking to the actual implementation, I didn't know where to look for that . I'm not familiar with that syntax (having multiple declaration of a function above each other). I tried changing the exampe to `public transform<T>(arr1: ReadonlyArray<T>, arr2: ReadonlyArray<T>): Array<T>;
    public transform(arr1: any[], arr2: any[]): any[] {
        return [...arr1, ...arr2];
    }`, but still get the same error :/.